# Traceback on 3 click house code

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm getting an invalid syntax(see error below)I'm suck with this error....help?  I am writing code to build a house in 4 clicks.  A lot of the code below is my trying different things so just ignore it(or give me suggestions with what I should do)  It's the p2 error that has me stumped.

```
<using graphics.py>
import graphics
from graphics import*

def house():
    win=GraphWin(800,500)
    win.setCoords(0.0,0.0,4.0,4.0)#reset coordinates
    Text(Point(2.0,3.5),"click spot to designate 2 corners of house").draw(win)
    p1=win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    side1=(Point(p1.getX(),(p1.getY()))
    p2=win.getMouse()<----------------------------ERROR with the p2
    p2.draw(win) 
    side2=(Point(p2.getX(),(p2.getY()))
    rect = Rectangle(side1,side2)
    rect.draw(win)

    #door- p3=center top edge of door
    msg2 = Text(Point(2.0,0.5),"click to designate top of door")
    msg2.draw(win)
    p3=win.getMouse()
    p3.draw(win)
    #golden:)
    Line(Point(p3.getX(),(p3.getY())),(Point(p2.getX()),(p2.getY()))).draw(win)
    """
    p3 = dwidth.getCenter()                             
    rectWidth = (p2.getX()) - (p1.getX())
    #doorWidth = door.setWidth(distance/5.0)#width 1/5 of house 
    dwidth= eval((rectWidth) / (5))
    dheight=((getP3(),(getP2()))#height = from top corners to bottom of the frame
    #door = Rectangle((dwidth) * (dheight))"""
    #door.draw(win)

    """#Window
    message3 = Text(Point(2.0, 1.0),"click to designate center of square     window").draw(win)
    p4=win.getMouse()
    p4.draw(win)
    c=door.getCenter()
    dx=p4.getX()-c.getX()
    dy=p4.getY()-c.getY()
    window = Rectangle(Point(dx,dx),Point(dy,dy))
    window.draw(win)
    #window side = half of door with
    #roof top = half way btwn l and r edges
    #house height = half height of house frame 
    #win.getMouse()
    #win.close
    """
    #window one forth of the door
    #window = Rectangle(p4)
    #window.setWidth(doorwidth/ 4.0)
    #window.draw(win)
house()



>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ICS 140\ass 8.py", line 57, in <module>
    house()
  File "E:\ICS 140\ass 8.py", line 28, in house
    Line(Point(p3.getX()),(p3.getY()),(Point(p2.getX()),(p2.getY()))).draw(win)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
>>>
```

Comment: For your first error, you don't `import Rectangle` anywhere. Your code doesn't know what `Rectangle` is. For your second error, it looks like the `Rectangle` class needs 3 arguments to be initialized, and you're only passing 2 (the 2 `Point` in there). I'm surprised this is giving you different errors on restarts? That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because a `Point` needs an `x` and a `y` argument, but you are only passing an `x` in the line where you try to create a `Rectangle`.

Not exactly sure what your code is trying to do, but hopefully this will help get you started in the right direction:

```
from graphics import *

def house():
    win=GraphWin(800,500)
    win.setCoords(0.0,0.0,3.0,4.0)#reset coordinates
    Text(Point(1.5,3.5),"click spot to designate 2 corners of house").draw(win)
    p1 = win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    p2 = win.getMouse()
    p2.draw(win)
    rectangle = Rectangle(p1, p2)
    rectangle.setWidth(3)
    rectangle.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

house()
```